# Issue deserializing json string

Tags: c#, json

I'm using newtonsoft json to deserialize a json string and write the contents into a datatable, run into errors. I'm able to get this working with JavaScriptSerializer class but not with newtonsoft json. Please point me where I am doing it wrong.

Please find json sample below.

**JSON:**

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Jason1",
        "LastName": "Test1",
        "Email": "123@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Jason2",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Email": "234@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    }
]
```

**C#:**

```
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Eligible { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertLogtime { get; set; }
    public object Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Profile> profile { get; set; }
}

var jstring = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(profile);
//string profile has data in the sample specified

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(string)));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < jstring.profile.Count; i++)
{
        try
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = jstring.profile[i].Id;
        dr["FirstName"] = jstring.profile[i].FirstName;
        dr["LastName"] = jstring.profile[i].LastName;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array because the type requires a JSON object to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
> collection interface like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
> JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: Please show the code that is actually deserializing.  It appears you are deserializing your JSON array into an object, which wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Hi @KirkWoll, I updated the OP where I do the deserializing of JSON array.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile[]>(profile);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Jason1",
        "LastName": "Test1",
        "Email": "123@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Jason2",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Email": "234@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    }
]
```

Is an array ([......]). So as the error says you must deserialze into an array

Like this

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile[]>(profile);
```